# Why can't I use variable like this a=(1,2)

Tags: python

Let's say a=(1,2) and b=(3,4)
What should print(a+b) give?

I expect the output (4,6), but the actual output is(1,2,3,4)

Comment: it is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/497885/python-element-wise-tuple-operations-like-sum)

Comment: Because that's how Python defines what addition means for `tuple`s.  If it behaved the way you want, then some other people would ask why `+` doesn't concatenate.  There's no pleasing everyone.  If you want to do element-wise addition, you'll need to do it yourself, possibly with your own class.

Answer (score 2):

`a` and `b` are of `tuple` type. The `+` operator for tuples append the tuples to one another. To actually sum element-wise tuples, you need to do the following:

```py
[sum(x) for x in zip(a,b)]
```

You can find more info here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16548756/4949074

Answer (score 1):

Because it is a tuple type which is a [sequence type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq) for which the `+` operator does concatenation and not addition. If you want numeric vectors, look at, e.g., [NumPy](https://scipy-lectures.org/intro/numpy/index.html).