# How do I add to my tuples value

Tags: python-3.x

This is an example of the code

```
    elif longitude > longitudel and latitude < latitudel:
            thor = 1,-1 + thor
```

I want it to change if say thor is = 1,1 I want it to become 2,0 I have been messing around with it for a while but I cant seem to find a way to get this to work and keep it as a tuple. Is there a way to keep it as a tuple or do I have to set seperate integers to get this to work ?

Comment: Can you properly format your code and provide a clear example that is easy to understand

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
thor = tuple(sum(x) for x in zip(thor, (1,-1)))
```

A shorter way would be:

```
thor = tuple(map(sum, zip(thor, (1,-1))))
```

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1169769/4737952).