# Addition with tuple in Python

Tags: python, tuples

here my two tuples :

```
tuple1 = (320,240)
tuple2 = (5,5)
```

I would like to add this two element like an addition like that :

```
finalTuple = (325, 245)
```

I know this question has been already asked but I didn't found my answer.
Thank you.

Comment: This seems to do what you need
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169725/adding-values-from-tuples-of-same-length

Comment: @ITried why didn't you flag it as duplicate?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1169760/7726310 this is exact what you are looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add tuples directly, you can use a a comprehension to add the tuples:

```
finalTuple = tuple(t1 + t2 for t1, t2 in zip(tuple1, tuple2))
```

If you want to add them like that: finalTuple = tuple1 + tuple2, you should convert them to numpy array, where the addition operator is defined like that.

```
tuple1 = np.array(tuple1)
tuple2 = np.array(tuple2)
finalTuple = tuple1 + tuple2
```

And you can convert it back to a tuple with:

```
finalTuple = tuple(finalTuple)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
final_tuple = tuple((i+j) for i,j in zip(tuple1, tuple2))
```

Comment: BTW, the inner parenthesis around `i+j` are not necessary (they have no effect)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
final_tuple = tuple(v + tuple2[i] for i, v in enumerate(tuple1))
```